# Is it a way to specify @DirtiesContext to only dirty after whole main test class when it contains @Nested classes?

Tags: spring-test

There seems to be no way to specify @DirtiesContext to avoid dirtying and reloading the context after each @Nested class.

I found a way to avoid that programmatically, however it would be nice to have an annotation parameter to achieve that, avoiding the need of a custom listener, which invalidates default listeners.

The mentioned custom listener

```
    /**
     * Disallow context dirtying for nested classes
     */
    public static final class TestDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener extends DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener {

        @Override
        protected void beforeOrAfterTestClass(TestContext testContext, DirtiesContext.ClassMode requiredClassMode) throws Exception {
            if ( ! testContext.getTestClass().getName().contains("$")) {
                super.beforeOrAfterTestClass(testContext, requiredClassMode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and set the following annotation on the top class:

`@NestedTestConfiguration(NestedTestConfiguration.EnclosingConfiguration.OVERRIDE)`

it will make this (and other annotations) to be needed to be overridden and not inherited(default since spring framework 5.3)
Additional information can be found on [Nested tests under spring test documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-nestedtestconfiguration)

Comment: Thanks, David. What concerns me about that mechanism is the "and other annotations" part. It would be desirable to have a more selective means of doing this, as maintaining all annotations in all nested classes looks like problematic.

Comment: I think that it was made to simplify the process as there are some combinations that are mutual exclusive, but maybe some opt-in mechanism might be a valid feature request.